# Is there any way to show kendo grid column only for particular rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new to kendo and beginner in kendo.Below kendo template for one column in kendo grid. But I want to display this buttons for particular rows only. Is there any way in kendo to that?

```
command: [
    {
        title: "Accept",
        template:"<button title='Accept' class='btn btn-success btn-flat' onclick='AcceptClick(this)'><span class='fa fa-check '></span> </button>"
    }, {
        title: "Reject",
        template: "<button title='Reject' class='btn btn-danger btn-flat' onclick='RejectClick(this)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>  </button>"
    }
],
title: "Action",
width: "160px"
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with your **template** but as a function like:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "name",
    template: function(dataItem) {
//your if condition can be coded here like: if (dataItem.someColumn){}
      return "<strong>" + kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.name) + "</strong>";
    }
  }],
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to maintain one flag variable for checking condition.
Based on the condition you can display and hide whatever you want to do
follow the code

```
template: function(data) {
    if (data.flagvalue == "some value") {
        return "<button title='Accept' class='btn btn-success btn-flat' onclick='AcceptClick(this)'><span class='fa fa-check '></span> </button>"
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```